# Custom Scheduler thread after launching is being run parallelly by main thread and workers of gunicorn

Tags: python-3.7, gunicorn, gevent

We have a scheduler service which gets spawned at the beginning of the program.

We moved our code base from python2 to python 3.

We are monkey patching with gevent before calling the scheduler thread.

Once the gunicorn starts with let's say two workers.

The scheduler_service run() method's code is forked and is served by all 3 threads in parallel.

We want only one thread to handle it. What could be the issue as with python2 and without monkey patching it was working fine?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how it should be behaving.  You need a singleton reference, shared among threads that allow for a master to take priority.  Usually a database model that tracks the current online threads, with a checkin, and a failover logic if one no longer checks in as master.